# JS - Call to static method with prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Well, I searched and didn't find a way to call a prototype method without instantiate another object. I found how to do:

```
 var x = new X();
 X.MyMethod();
```

What I really need to know is if there is a way to do like in jQuery, doing something like:

```
var x = "mystring";
x.MyMethod();
```

In jQuery UI, we call .draggable(), .resizable() in a selected object. Can I do the same?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. You can't really call string methods without having a string.

Comment: Are you trying to extend the native `String` prototype with your own methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extend the `String`'s prototype methods? You'll need to do something like this:

```
String.prototype.MyMethod = function() {
    console.log("MyMethod()");
};

var x = "mystring";
x.MyMethod();
```

See also: [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work?rq=1)

Or if you want to be really clever, study: [MDN Reference: Define Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Would be there a way to I get and manipulate the content of the passed string in my lambda function?

Comment: Yes. Inside of that function, the variable `this` will return the value of the `string` and you can manipulate it as you wish

Comment: @sxnine - strings are immutable so you cannot change the current string object in a method.  You can create a new string and return that from a method, but the current string object can't be changed.

Comment: right on, i should've been more clear. it'll throw an error if you try to mutate `this`. good call.